# updating handlebarJS precompiler

Tags: node.js, cordova, requirejs, handlebars.js

i am using handlebars pre-compiler for compiling handlebar templates using the command

```
handlebars *.tpl -f *.js
```

i am using handlebar.runtime-v1.1.2.js for using pre-compiled handlebar templates.

When is execute the compiled template with the following code

```
Handlebars.template('****');
```

am getting an error

```
Uncaught Error: Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 1.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (<= 1.0.rc.2).
```

can anyone guide me to update the handlebar pre-compiler to the latest one on linux machine.

Comment: How is RequireJS a factor in this question?